# $.get() and fetch() getting HTML body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stuck with one small issue. Rewriting js file from jQuery to native JS, and in jQuery we use:

```
$.get(`/page`, function (data) {
        elem.html(data);
}
```

basically we fetching body from '/page' and pushing it to elem.innerHTML.

But how I can get html body using fetch() instead of .get()?

Comment: The documentation for [using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) might be helpful.

Comment: no, I still can't get body, maybe to tired) but docs doesn't help in this case

Comment: You have backticks instead of quotes in your jQuery code, maybe you made the same mistake with fetch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like the equivalent:

```
fetch('/page').then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
}).then(function(string) {
    elem.innerHTML = string;
});
```

`fetch()` returns a promise that resolves to a `Response` object. The `text()` method of the `Response` returns a promise that resolves to the body of the response as a string. You then put that string into the HTML.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jkhxzdkg/)

Comment: I tried this before, and it doesn't work, that's why I'm confused

Comment: I was using the jQuery `.html()` method. I've changed it to plain JS `.innerHTML`. I just tested it and it works.

Comment: this works! fetch('/page').then(res => { response.text().then(string => { elem.innerHTML = string})});      this not, why? fetch('/page').then(res => { return response.text()}).then(string => { elem.innerHTML = string});

Comment: Neither should work, since you used `res` as the parameter name but `response` in the function body.

Comment: The second one works for me when I fix the typo: https://jsfiddle.net/jkhxzdkg/2/

Comment: hm, maybe I was really tired, spend almost a hour yesterday on this code)) Thanks!