# Can I replace a jQuery.load() one-liner with an equivalent fetch() call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fetch, one-liner

I have a page that uses the jQuery one liner

```
$('#id').load('/url');
```

to load a fragment into the DOM at a specific place.

If I want to remove the dependency on jQuery, is there an easy alternative way to do this — possibly with the relatively new fetch() API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting html from fetch request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523188/getting-html-from-fetch-request)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921805/fetch-api-to-get-html-response

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004048/get-and-fetch-getting-html-body

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need the equivalent of .load() to JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901116/i-need-the-equivalent-of-load-to-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like so:

```
fetch('/url')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(value => {
    document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = value
  });
```

Comment: Note: if you have any <script> in your response it wont run as opposed to $.load

Comment: it's there a way to load script portion?

Answer (score 1):

Almost a one liner :)

```js
;(async () => {
    document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = await (await fetch('/url')).text();
})();
```

to put it to some practical use you'd have at least to check the response code, so I'd first refactor it like this

```
;(async () => {
    let res = await fetch('/url');
    if(res.ok){
        document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = await res.text();   
    }
    else { ... }
})();
```

error handling is still missing, but I'm sure you get the picture :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

```
fetch('/method')
.then(response=> response.text())
.then(res => { document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = res; });
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I get `[object response]` in the page instead of the HTML snippet.

Comment: Actually it is working, I forget to convert response.

Comment: Now your answer is no different then @Magiczne's answer.